# IPTables rules re-appearing

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04, ufw

Folks,
I created two machines on SoftLayer's cloud. The machines are Ubuntu 10.4 64 bit, minimal config. I am running into a really strange problem that I have no idea where it is coming from.

The machines seem to have a default. very complex iptables rule set. I flushed the iptables and was able to verify that the machines were reachable. After a few hours, the iptables rules seem to re-appear.

The machine also has UFW installed. Creating a UFW rule to allow port 8080 (used by my application) does not seem to work either.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks.

-Raj

Comment: Did you check your system log files `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` for any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Running `dpkg-reconfigure ufw` will give you a bit more control over it, once you get the package doing exactly what you want you can reload the config running `service ufw restart`

In Lucid it has been converted to use upstart, which is a pain to manage, don't even get me started... :D

Let me know how it goes and good luck!

Comment: Hi Lynxman, thanks for your response. But do you know why/how iptables rules are re-appearing automatically even after I flush them

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think that has to do with the ufw reloading after log rotation, but since I wasn't certain I didn't say anything :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `ufw` is just a 'front-end' to `iptables`.

Since you're using ufw, that might be the problem.

My suggestion is to ditch ufw altogether and learn using iptables.